# What does a torque flange measure?

Tags: torque

If i mount a torque flange so that it connects 2 axles. Does it measure the difference between the torque applied to each axle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you refer to something like the following:

[image]

This is a torque measurement device that measures the torque which is carried by each shaft.
I.e. assuming

- you have two shafts connected with the torque flange and
- if one shaft is driven by a motor with **torque M** on one end
- and the other shaft is driving a generator (or a brake)

Then if the system is not accelerating or decelerating rotationally, the torque sensor should read torque M (i.e. all torque supplied by the motor will "go through" the torque flange -- and the shafts for that matter-- and will be consumed at the generator/brake).

If on the other hand the system is increasing or decreasing the rpm, then the torque sensor will only read part of the torque (and with a lot of oscillations) -- the part of the torque that will go through the flange has to do with the acceleration of the rotational masses past the torque flange.

---

In general the torque flanges usually use a strain gage principle. I.e. when torque passes through the flange it create a twisting angle. That angle can be measured and because of the calibration of the torque flange sensor it is possible to know what is the torque "passing through" the sensor.

Comment: Yes i mean flanges like this one.

So it depends on how i mount the flange? If i reverse the direction another torque is measured? Initially i thought torque flanges would work like this: https://i.imgur.com/2AbzZMC.png , like a rotational spring and the flange torque would be c (phi_2 - phi_1)

Comment: It shouldn't really matter which way you mount it - however read the documentation. Also regarding how they work, if I understood correctly your image (btw you should put it inline with the question), yes they work like a torsional spring ( a very stiff one).